# Why is the 'sex in the cockpit' question off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14759/62) attracted an unusual number of downvotes and is currently on hold as off-topic. I think it would be useful to discuss why: in my opinion there's no obvious reason to either downvote it or consider it  off-topic.

Both the question and one comment mentioned safety, and sex in the cockpit has indeed been implicated in accidents before (e.g. [this NTSB report](http://ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20001212X18632&key=1&queryId=162b5346-3ff7-4b10-99f4-cfa68f6670ae&pgno=10&pgsize=20)). And in a wider cultural context sex and aviation are frequently linked: the mile-high club, pilots having affairs with cabin crew etc. I also find it hard to see any reasonable justification for why [questions about using the toilet](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=toilet) on aircraft are on-topic, but sex on an aircraft is off-topic.

If we are going to consider questions like this off-topic on this site, we should come to a consensus on why, so that we can be consistent and explain it clearly. I'd be especially interested in comments from the people who voted to close the question.

Answer (score 6):

[The  original version](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/14759/1) that got closed contained only the question `How common is/was it?` that to me is unfair to compare to the technical questions about the toilets, that question had nothing technical or relevant to aviation and was better left to chat. (We do not have a question `How many times does a person go to the toilet?`, do we?)

[The current rewording](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/14759/2) is indeed better than the original, but in my opinion still focuses on the act rather than its aviation relevance. If it gets reworded/edited to contain only the last question of the current three, to me it could be reopened without problems. I refrain from doing it myself as it would significantly alter the original intentions of the post, and thus must be the author the one that does such a significant edit.

As per the votes, I cannot comment, as I have not cast mine.

EDIT:
what seems to be [the final version](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/revisions/14759/6) to me is acceptable and on-topic. Despite the "does it happen" part not being totally removed, is no more the main focus of the question and thus is much less of a problem compared to the one that got closed.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't cast a vote on it yet and this is the first time I've read it, but it seems rather unlikely to be answerable in its current state. I can't imagine that there are any reliable statistics on this since it seems quite unlikely that the participants would be likely enough to admit it for such statistics to be developed. Indeed, the current most-upvoted answer says almost exactly that in addition to providing a single anecdote in which it appears likely to have caused a GA crash.

Specifically, the part of it that seems unlikely to have a reliable answer is the "how common is it?" part of the question. Whether it has ever happened, on the other hand, seems much more answerable.

As far as "Is it safe?"... well, let's just say that has lots of possible answers and will probably vary by aircraft and by definition of 'safe.'

**edit**: Well, it looks like the title was fixed to remove the part about "how common is it" within a few minutes of when I originally posted this answer. I think it's probably fine to leave open now.

Answer (score 2):

The only problematic aspect I see in the question is the answers will be mostly opinions, as *reirab* wrote.

Exceptions would be safety reports. If this is what is looked for, then the question should be improved and focused on this aspect.

So not off-topic, but attracting opinion-based answers.